# Remove "You will be redirected to the PayPal website."

Tags: checkout, paypal, payment, paypal-express

How can I remove this line?

[image]

It appears by default under the Paypal option in checkout form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to know in which file you need to hide the text "**You will be redirected to the paypal website**" , you can use **Magento template path hints** here :  **system> configuration > Advanced > Developer** ....

than switch to **current store under Current configuration scope**

than **enable template path hints** under **Debug** ,  than you can see from which file the text "**You will be redirected to the paypal website**" is coming from....

you can see below links for more information  :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24273443/in-magento-1-9-0-0-how-can-i-enable-template-path-hint

http://support.magerewards.com/article/1534-how-do-i-turn-on-template-path-hints

Answer (score 0):

Goto the below folder

```
vendor/magento/module-paypal/view/frontend/web/template/payment/paypal-express.html
```

And override the files into your theme folder and remove the line.